# Error when setting up mysql cluster

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

I am trying to set up the mysql cluster. But when I try to start the mysqld(API) node, I get this error:

```
2014-12-02 17:02:37 0 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2014-12-02 17:02:37 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2014-12-02 17:02:37 4792 [Warning] Using pre 5.5 semantics to load error messages from /usr/share/mysql/.
2014-12-02 17:02:37 4792 [Warning] If this is not intended, refer to the documentation for valid usage of --lc-messages-dir and --language parameters.
2014-12-02 17:02:37 4792 [ERROR] Can't read from messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'
2014-12-02 17:02:37 4792 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2014-12-02 17:02:37 4792 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-12-02 17:02:37 4792 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2014-12-02 17:02:37 4792 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-12-02 17:02:37 4792 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2014-12-02 17:02:37 4792 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2014-12-02 17:02:37 4792 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-12-02 17:02:37 4792 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2014-12-02 17:02:37 4792 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-12-02 17:02:37 4792 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2014-12-02 17:02:37 4792 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-12-02 17:02:37 4792 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-12-02 17:02:37 4792 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2014-12-02 17:02:37 4792 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2014-12-02 17:02:37 4792 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.21 started; log sequence number 1601578
2014-12-02 17:02:37 4792 [Note] NDB: Changed global value of binlog_format from STATEMENT to MIXED
2014-12-02 17:02:37 4792 [Note] NDB: NodeID is 4, management server '172.26.15.106:1186'
2014-12-02 17:02:37 4792 [Note] NDB[0]: NodeID: 4, all storage nodes connected
2014-12-02 17:02:37 4792 [Warning] NDB: server id set to zero - changes logged to bin log with server id zero will be logged with another server id by slave mysqlds
2014-12-02 17:02:37 4792 [Note] Starting Cluster Binlog Thread
2014-12-02 17:02:37 4792 [Note] NDB Binlog: Ndb object created with reference : 0x80040004, name : Ndb Binlog schema change monitoring
2014-12-02 17:02:37 4792 [Note] NDB Binlog: Ndb object created with reference : 0x80050004, name : Ndb Binlog data change monitoring
2014-12-02 17:02:37 4792 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-12-02 17:02:37 4792 [Note] Binlog end
2014-12-02 17:02:37 4792 [Note] Stopping Cluster Utility thread
2014-12-02 17:02:38 4792 [Note] Stopping Cluster Binlog
2014-12-02 17:02:38 4792 [Note] Stopping Cluster Index Stats thread
2014-12-02 17:02:38 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2014-12-02 17:02:38 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2014-12-02 17:02:38 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ndb_transid_mysql_connection_map'
2014-12-02 17:02:38 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ndbinfo'
2014-12-02 17:02:38 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ndbcluster'
2014-12-02 17:02:38 4792 [Note] Stopping Cluster Index Statistics thread
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2014-12-02 17:02:39 4792 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2014-12-02 17:02:41 4792 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1601588
2014-12-02 17:02:41 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2014-12-02 17:02:41 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2014-12-02 17:02:41 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2014-12-02 17:02:41 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2014-12-02 17:02:41 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2014-12-02 17:02:41 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2014-12-02 17:02:41 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2014-12-02 17:02:41 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2014-12-02 17:02:41 4792 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
```

I am using `mysql-cluster-gpl-7.3.7-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64.tar.gz` for installing and the config files are following the files discussed here `http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-install-configuration.html`.
I checked online for ways to solve `Can't read from messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'`, but all of them failed. So I don't know how to solve this problem without using mysql 5.6.
My computer is using Ubuntu 13

Comment: Off-topic: try serverfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent over 10 hours on this question and the command that works is running sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-file="/etc/my.cnf" on the API machine.